# hg convert - trying to move a directory from one repo to another

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

So I have a directory called `flash`. I'd like to move it totally from an existing Mercurial repo located at `~/wdm` to another existing Mercurial repo, located at `~/wdm-js`.

I've been told this is possible with `hg convert`, but I don't really know how this works. I have tried the following, but think I may have got something wrong.

Having [read up on the hg convert for Mercurial docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial), I've created a filemap, which reads as follows:

```
include flash
```

Then I've gone to ~/wdm and run the following command:

```
$ hg convert . ~/wdm-js --filemap ~/filemap.txt
```

I've seen a load of output as follows:

```
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
413 [doc/design][m]: first stab at a design doc for model (sent to list).
[412 more history items]
```

So this looks fairly promising. But when I look at wdm-js there is no `flash` directory there. And none of the `flash` directory files have moved from the `wdm` directory. And the `hg status` of both repos looks no different.

Do I still have to copy the `flash` directory across manually, and `hg add`/`hg remove` all the files manually to both repos?

Or... should this have been done for me, meaning that I have messed up in some way?

Answer (score 4):

`hg convert` doesn't update the working directory in the destination repository (it leaves it at the original null revision), so do a `hg update` there to see the files.  Also, the way you ran it, it **copies** the files; you can either delete them from the original repository via `hg forget` or `hg remove`, or use `hg convert` again using a filemap with the line:

```
exclude flash
```

Comment: Hm - if I do an 'hg update' in the destination repo, it just says '0 files changed...'. I don't think I ran it right...?

Comment: ...do I have to do anything other the 'hg update' to copy the files over?

Comment: @AP257: the command line looks OK. Is flash in the root of your repo? If not, you'll need to specify the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

To copy into existing repository you need first copy flash folder into new repository as you did it with convert command and then push the changes from new repository into existing target repository.